# Vector`s end iterator content

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I have 2 questions regarding following examples:
1)

```
std::vector<int> v(5,1);
cout << *v.end();
```

Is a printed result is undefined (depends on compiler)

2)

```
int x = 5,y = 6;
std::vector<int*> pv;
pv.push_back(&x);
pv.push_back(&y);
cout << *pv.end();
```

Is a printed result is undefined (depends on compiler) or NULL

Comment: I don't understand what difference you're trying to illustrate with the two examples. In both cases, dereferencing the `end` iterator is undefined behavior. Maybe you're looking for [`vector::back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back)?

Comment: *(depends on compiler)* => not quite, **undefined behavior** means that you are not writing C++ any longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no item at `end()`, it's an iterator right after the last valid item in your vector.

```
*v.end();
```

It's ***undefined behavior***. You can use `end()` for comparing an iterator whether it's pointing to the item after last item or not.

Easy way to access the value of last item is [`back()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back), for example:

```
cout << v.back();
```

Answer (score 2):

The `end()` iterator points to a position that is one element **after** the last element of the container. Accessing the data that it points to will invoke **undefined behavior** and this is the case in both your examples.

Answer (score 1):

Dereferencing past the end is will probably end badly but it looks like it is *implementation defined*, if we look at the draft C++ standard section `24.21` *Iterator requirements* and then to `24.2.1` *In general* paragraph *5* says (*emphasis mine*):

> Just as a regular pointer to an array guarantees that there is a pointer value pointing past the last element of the array, so for any iterator type there is an iterator value that points past the last element of a corresponding sequence. These values are called past-the-end values. **Values of an iterator i for which the expression *i is defined are called dereferenceable. The library never assumes that past-the-end values are dereferenceable.*** Iterators can also have singular values that are not associated with any sequence. [ Example: After the declaration of an uninitialized pointer x (as with int x;), x must always be assumed to have a singular value of a pointer. —end example ] **Results of most expressions are undefined for singular values**; [...] **Dereferenceable values are always non-singular.**

Comment: In order to make it implementation-defined, the standard has to explicitly require implementations to define it. I don't believe there is a requirement for implementations to document what happens when the past-the-end iterators are dereferenced.

Comment: @AndreyT I see what you are saying, although I still don't see that it is as undefined, or at least I can not find the section that does. The language is definitely vague, *never assumes* is not the same as *undefined*.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, in both cases the *behavior* is undefined. Note, that is not "the printed result" that is undefined. You code does not even get a chance to print anything. A mere application of `*` operator to end iterator already causes undefined behavior. E.g. this alone

```
*v.end();
```

is already undefined behavior.

Secondly, undefined in this case does not mean "depends on the compiler". *Implementation-defined* behavior depends on the compiler. *Undefined* means "completely unpredictable", even if you are using the same compiler.

P.S. There's seems to be a bit of ongoing work in the standard commitee with reagard to some closely related issues.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#208

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-active.html#1213

Hopefully it will result in a clearer specification of what is legal and what is not for the past-the-end iterators. But it is clear that in general case past-the-end iterator can legally be a singular iterator, meaning that in general case it can be non-dereferenceable.

Comment: It actually looks to be implementation defined, which I was not expecting.

Comment: @Shafik Yaghmour: I read your quote, but I don't see how you drew that conclusion from it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both of those are undefined.

Answer (score 0):

`vector::end` - Return iterator to end (public member function )

You can read more [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/end/).

---

Your **first example**:

```
    std::vector<int> v(5,1);
    cout << *(v.end()-1);
```

It's **undefined** (look at the picture), `v.end()` is pointing to the address after the last element and if the container is empty, this function returns the same as `v.begin()`.
[image]

And your **second example**:

```
    int x = 5,y = 6;
    std::vector<int*> pv;
    pv.push_back(&x);
    pv.push_back(&y);
    cout << **(pv.end()-1);
```

Comment: It's not because it is 0 base. You don't do `pv.begin()-1` for first element because its "0 base". It's rather about the `end()` is pointing to the address **after** the last element which has nothing to do with being 0 base.

Comment: @MehdiTaxir: Answer to what??? The only questions the OP has asked so far is whether the behavior is *undefined* or not. How does your post answer these questions?

Comment: @AndreyT: Well this is undefined, the explanations are clear and the same result would have.